# automatically passing a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

i want to easily pass down a variable into a function, but I do not want to write `var=var` in every function, but I want to keep the code in functions so I can navigate it, is there an easy way.

this is how the code could look:

```py
class main():
    def __init__(self,boolean):
        self.boolean = boolean

    def change(self, change_to):
        def boolchange(self = self, change_to = change_to):
            self.boolean = change_to
        if change_to != self.boolean:
            boolchange()

main(True)
main.boolchange(False)
print(self.boolean)

> False
```

now how I imagine the code could look like is:

```py
class main():
    def __init__(self,boolean):
        self.boolean = boolean

    def change(self, change_to):
        def boolchange():
            self.boolean = change_to
        if change_to != self.boolean:
            boolchange()

main(True)
main.boolchange(False)
print(self.boolean)

> False
```

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about how Python classes/functions work. You don't need `self` in `boolchange` at all since it is closure, and you also don't need to do `var=var` every time, but only in cases you want to provide default values

Comment: Use partial application: [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: It seems to useless to only change if values are different, just assign and you'll get the same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Your method call can be replaced with `main.boolean = False`. Can you expand on your example to give a better use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some misconceptions about how Python classes/functions work. You don't need `self` in `boolchange` at all since it is closure (to be honest, you don't need `boolchange` at all.), and you also don't need to do `var=var` every time, but only in cases you want to provide default values.

```
class main():
    def __init__(self, boolean):
        self.boolean = boolean

    def change(self, change_to):
        self.boolean = change_to


m = main(True)
m.change(False)
print(m.boolean)
# False
```

You can also easily implement a `toggle` method, which seems to be what you tried to do:

```
class main():
    def __init__(self, boolean):
        self.boolean = boolean

    def toggle(self):
        self.boolean = not self.boolean


m = main(True)
m.toggle()
print(m.boolean)
# False
m.toggle()
print(m.boolean)
# True
```